# Matlab FFT for gaussian function

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to obtain `gaussian curve` by using matlab's fft. The problem is that in one case my attemp to reduce noise by dividing `F=dt.*F./exp(-1i.*nu.*T/2)` is not working (img 1) and in the second case if I am trying to take absolute value of fft result's I dont have decent scale in graph (img 2).

```
N=512;
T=10;
dt=T/(N-1);
t=linspace(-5,5,N);
f=exp(-t.^2);
F=fft(f);

F1=F(1:N/2+1);
F2=F(N/2+1:N);
F=[F2,F1];

dnu=(N-1)/(N*T);
nuNyq=1/(2*dt);
nu=-nuNyq+dnu*(0:N);
F=dt.*F;
%F=dt.*F./exp(-1i.*nu.*T/2);


y=linspace(-5,5,N);
F2=pi.^(1/2).*exp(-y.^2/4);

hold on
plot(y,F2); 
%plot(nu,real(F),'r');
plot(nu,abs(F),'r');
legend('analiticFT','FFT')
xlim([-5 5])
hold off
```

img 1
[image: img. 1]

img2
[image: img. 2]

Comment: Just a note, it is much easier to help you when you give your variables meaningful names. (Note 2: to achieve what you are doing with F1 and F2 you can call `fftshift(F)`)

Comment: What do you mean with _is not working?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the scaling in your formula for the analytic Fourier Transform is not quite correct. According to [this Fourier Transform table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions), the transform of the continuous time-domain signal

[image: y\left(t\right) = e^{-a t^2}]

is

[image: Y\left(f\right) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \cdot e^{-\frac{\left(\pi f\right)^2}{a}}]

where in your case `a=1`. Correspondingly, you should compare the FFT of the time domain signal

```
t=linspace(-5,5,N);
f=exp(-t.^2);
```

with the analytic Fourier Transform

```
F2 = sqrt(pi)*exp(-(pi*y).^2);
```

So, plotting the comparison with:

```
hold off;
plot(y,F2); 
hold on;
plot(nu,abs(F),'r');
legend('analiticFT','FFT')
xlim([-5 5])
```

yields:

[image]

Now that we have establish a proper basis for comparison, we can look at why you are getting the oscillations in `img 1`. Simply put, the reference Gaussian pulse `f=exp(-t.^2);` you have generated has a peak at `t=0`. The corresponding *"zero"* discrete time instant is naturally the first index in the array (index 1). However in your array, this peak appears at index `N/2`. Under the [Shift theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem), this causes an additional `exp(-pi*j*k)` term in the frequency domain, responsible for the oscillations you are seeing. To fix this, you should shift back your Gaussian pulse with `ifftshift`:

```
F=fftshift(fft(ifftshift(f)));
```