# FFTW libray: how to properly plot an output?

Tags: c, math, signal-processing, fft, fftw

I'm having some problems with the FFTW libray, I'm testing the Fast Fourier Transform algorithm with a Gaussian, therefore I would expect to get another Gaussian when I do the transform, this is what I get though:

[image: Plot of the output]

The code is the following (I am using C):

[image: Code]

Could you please help me and tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Do not use images to your output and code. Please, post it the needed information of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab FFT for gaussian function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367889/matlab-fft-for-gaussian-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the calculations you have made, but in the interpretation you do of the data. It is important to consider the gaussian you have passed and how is it phased in respect to the origin.  You can expect a real gaussian **ONLY** if you passed an origin centered gaussian also.  You got a gaussian multiplied by `exp(i*phase*omega)` as the original data was not most probably origin centered.  If you check the imaginary values you'll see that they are also oscillating and dephased `M_PI*0.25` with respect to the real part.  The data for a zero centered real function should go from `N/2` to `N-1` for the negative values (in a complement to N fashion) and then from `0` to `N/2-1` for the positive samples.  Most probably you centered your gaussian around sample `N/2` (I've just checked, and you have done precisely this :) ) and this produced the complex exponential multiplying in your output.

Also, the origin is at element `0`, so it is properly reflected at the origin.  Just center your input gaussian to the same point and see how it doesn't show such an oscillating result.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve the problem with your help.